# What are the benefits of doing pvcreate on a partition instead of on device?

Tags: partition, lvm

I learnt yesterday that I could pvcreate directly on /dev/sdb instead of /dev/sdb1. I thought that you could only pvcreate on a existing partition. Doing it on a partition adds a level and operations so what are the benefits of creating a partition before doing pvcreate?

Comment: Related question: *[Uses of single-partition disk configuration](https://superuser.com/q/1181320/432690)*.

Comment: Actually there's another reason, and simply rephrasing this answer isn't useful to anyone.  Directly creating the partition interferes with resizing the volumes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons to do so.

1. If the partition does not allocate 100% of the space of the device, this allows you to assign only a part of the device to LVM, hence leaving the rest of the device available for other uses.
2. In the case of a partition allocating all the device space, the reason is that if the disk is accessed by other non-Linux OSes, they might not recognize LVM and see the unpartitioned disk as a clean slate. Making a partition on it signals that the disk is being used for something.

Comment: Thanks! I also read about block alignement? Is it a reason as well?

Comment: @Pozinux No, this has nothing to do with it.